# props state values in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS trying to make a quiz app. In the game form user has to  input country names and will get a point for every correct answer.The final score will be shown in Result form but cant get the state score value to Result.js form . The props command is the handleSubmit function ,using 'points' as an attribute

Game form js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './game.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import Result from '../Result/Result'
class game extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            dataIsLoaded : false,
            answer:'',
            countries:[],
            index:0,
            links : [],
            submitimes:1,
            countriesnames:[],
            score:0,
            temp:0
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleSkip=this.handleSkip.bind(this);
        this.handleHint=this.handleHint.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.state.dataIsLoaded===false)
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        await axios.get('https://peaceful-temple-16111.herokuapp.com/https://salty-cove-08526.herokuapp.com/api/countries?format=json')
            .then(res => {
                console.log("fetched data")
                this.setState({ countries: res.data });
                let links = []
                this.state.countries.map(country =>
                    links.push(country.photo)
                )
                let countriesnames=[]
                this.state.countries.map(country=>
                    countriesnames.push(country.name)
                )
                console.log(countriesnames)
                this.setState({
                    links,
                    countriesnames,
                    dataIsLoaded: true,
                    answer:''
                })
            })
    }

    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        
        e.preventDefault();  

            if(this.state.answer==""){
                alert("Please enter Country Name before Submitting")
            }else{
                if(this.state.countriesnames[this.state.index].toLowerCase()==this.state.answer.toLowerCase()){
                    this.setState({
                        score:this.state.score + 1
                    })
                    if(this.state.submitimes==3){
                        this.setState({
                            temp:this.state.temp+1
                        })
                    }
              
              
                    console.log("score=",this.state.score)
                }else{
                    console.log("score=",this.state.score)
                 
                }
                console.log("userinput=",this.state.answer)

                this.setState({
                    index: this.state.index + 1,
                    submitimes:this.state.submitimes+1,
                    answer:""
                })
                console.log('index=',this.state.index)
                console.log('times=',this.state.submitimes)
            
               
            }
            
    
            <Result points={this.state.score}/> /////<=here
            window.location="/result"
        }
    }
```

Result form js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import './Result.css'
import Game from '../game/game'

class Result extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <section className="result">
                    <div className="lContainer">
                        <div class="rheading">
                            Congratulation's your Score was:
                        </div >
                        <div className="points">{this.props.points}</div> /////<=here
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Result;
```

Comment: why you need this window.location="/result"

Comment: to redirect to result js form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must note that React is a `Single Page application`. And to introduce Routes in your Application you will need a third party library, `react-router-dom` is one of those libraries.

So, doing `window.location="/result"` doesn't mean anything here. In Single Page application, we don't have a seperate HTML page called `results.html`. It's just one huge `SPA (index.html)` and everything goes with our `root` div in our `index.html` in the public folder.

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

I will not go with each and every detail about `react-router-dom` . Go through this documentation to get started.

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

**UPDATE:** From comment, It seems you also wants to know about passing the `score` to Child Component.

To link b/w different components in your app, you should go with `react-router-dom` as mentioned above.

**CASE B:** In order to pass the `score` to the `Result` component, you do not need to use `<Result points={this.state.score} />` nor `window.location` in your `handleSubmit()` method. The way you have done this will result in error in your app.

You simply need to use your `Result` component within `Game` component inside the `render()` function within `return()`.

**Game.js** Should look like below code. So that `Result` Component gets rendered within `Game` Component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Result from "./Result";

class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      score: 34
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Result points={this.state.score} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

a) Also I checked that you have imported `Game` Component in `Result` Component. That is not needed at all. This will ultimately mean You will render a parent component `Game` in the child component `Result`.

**FULL CODE DEMO OF HOW BOTH YOU YOUR COMPONENTS SHOULD LOOK LIKE :**

```js
const {Component} = React;

class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      score: 34
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Result points={this.state.score} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Result extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="result">
          <div className="lContainer">
            <div class="rheading">Congratulation's your Score was:</div>
            <div className="points">{this.props.points}       </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so window.location is the reason state score value is not being sent to resultjs ?

Comment: @No, My Friend :) The reason is you are using <Result points={this.state.score}/> at the wrong place within your submit. And window.location will simply throw you the error once you submit.

Comment: Do one thing, Create your render function and return some JSX from it and use  Use your  `<Result points={this.state.score}/>` . I will show you the Demo in a while :) So that you understand the concept fully and wouldn't mix two things...Don't worry..Just give me a moment

Comment: Have updated my answer. Check this. I hope this will be helpful :)